# Check for valid date with datepicker

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker and the user can manually put a date in the datepicker.

But if the user doesnt't fill in the correct date format the user has to noticed about that.

The correct date format has to be:

dd-mm-jj

This is the datepicker:

```
  @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.IngangsDatum, Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.IngangsDatum).Min("01-01-2009").Max(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, 12, 31)).Format("dd-MM-yyyy").ParseFormats(new string[] { "ddMMyyyy" }).Events(e => e.Change("OnIngangsDatumChanged")))
```

But what I have to change?

Thank you

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ParseFormats` like your wanted format, e.g. `dd-MM-yyyy` as you have set in `Format`. Then add a `change` event to check and notify user about any errors:

```
change: function(e) {
    if (this.value()) {
        window.alert("Valid date");
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Invalid date");
    }
}
```

In the change event, `this.value()` will return `null` if the date is not valid.

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aWeHum)